# Magento 2 : How Can I get Selected Payment Details on Next Step

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, checkout, knockoutjs

Using knockout js, I have created a custom step, which I have place after payment method. I need to show which payment method was selected by the user.

I am creating a custom step as summary step. I want to display shipping address, shipping method and payment method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do this things.

1. In your custom step js file, Include this file

   ```
   vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\js\checkout-data.js
   ```
2. After inluding file, used object of that file into your code and call the function `getSelectedPaymentMethod`.
3. That function give you information which you can used further.

Comment: Your solution works but it show this way "authorizenet_directpost". Can i get it in proper text

Comment: That is magento payment code. You can get payment method label easly from payment code.

Comment: Can you give me the method which will give me proper name of payment method?